# Gerrit MySQL configuration

Tags: maven, gerrit

Hi I have installed Gerrit on my Desktop at home it works fine with internet.
However,
When i Wanted to install Gerrit with MySQL in Office server(Doesn't have an internet connection). I have been prompted to download MySQL_connector.jar file from Maven repository on the internet this step often fails.
Is there any workaround for this step. So that I can configure MYSQL with gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but download the file and place it in the `lib/` folder. Maybe `gerrit init` picks it up.